# Prawn, prawnto and templates

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, prawn, prawnto

sorry for my english.

I am trying to user prawn and prawnto on my application. I have a pdf file to use as template, the pdf file has only one page and that page just has a header and a footer, then, I have this on my controller:

```
  def index

    @search = User.search(params[:search])
    @users = @search.paginate(:page => params[:page])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @users   }
      format.xml  { render xml: @users }
      format.xlsx { export2xlsx(@search.relation.to_xlsx :columns => [:cod_cia, :cod_emp, :login, :email]) }
      format.pdf  { render :layout => false }
      prawnto :prawn => { :template => "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/pdfs/template1.pdf" }
    end

  end
```

All good, except that the template is rendered only at the first generated page, the other pages has not the template.

Somebody know how I can get the template repeat in my all generated pages?

Thk in advance.
Regards.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about prawnto, but with prawn you can tell it to not auto create the first page. Then add each page manually with a template.

```
filename = "/path/to/template.pdf"
Prawn::Document.generate("output.pdf", :skip_page_creation => true) do
  start_new_page(:template => filename)
  text "First page"
  start_new_page(:template => filename)
  text "Second page"
end
```